# Sorting Org entry properties in an arbitrary specified order

Tags: org-mode

I have some Org entry user properties which I want to keep in a specific order (not necessarily alphabetical) at the top of the properties drawer: `(defconst my-properties-in-order '("A" "B" "C"))`.

Given an Org entry like:

```
* Heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :B:             valB
  :C:             valC
  :X:             valX
  :A:             valA
  :Y:             valY
  :END:
```

I'm looking for a function which orders the properties according to `my-properties-in-order` while placing other properties below (preserving their relative rank), so that the transformed entry looks like this:

```
* Heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :A:             valA
  :B:             valB
  :C:             valC
  :X:             valX
  :Y:             valY
  :END:
```

I know I can use `(org-entry-properties nil 'standard)` to get all an entries standard properties and `org-entry-put` to write properties, but the sorting and safe deletion of the properties drawer with the old order remains. Also, there might be a better way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job but doesn't preserve the case of property names and removes `+`'s:

```lisp
(defconst my-properties-in-order '("A" "B" "C"))

(defun my-org-entry-sort-properties ()
  "Sorts entry properties according to `my-properties-in-order`.
Properties not in that list are but at the end, in their orginal order."
  (interactive)
  (let ((order my-properties-in-order)
        (inprops (org-entry-properties nil 'standard))
        outprops)
    (setq inprops (delq (assoc "CATEGORY" inprops) inprops))
    (setq inprops (nreverse inprops))
    (setq outprops
          (sort inprops
                (lambda (x y)
                  (let* ((posx (cl-position (car x) order :test 'string=))
                         (posy (cl-position (car y) order :test 'string=)))
                    (cond ((and posx posy)
                           (< posx posy))
                          ((and posx (not posy))
                           t)
                          ((and (not posx) posy)
                           nil)
                          (t
                           nil))))))
    (mapc (lambda (x) (org-entry-delete nil (car x))) outprops)
    (mapc (lambda (x) (org-entry-put nil (car x) (cdr x))) outprops)))
```

Below is a version which retains case and `+`'s:

```lisp
(defun my-org-entry-sort-properties ()
  "Sorts entry properties according to `my-properties-in-order`.
Properties not in that list are but at the end, in their orginal order."
  (interactive)
  (let ((order my-properties-in-order)
        (inprops (org-entry-properties-preserve-case))
        outprops)
    (setq inprops (nreverse inprops))
    (setq outprops
          (sort inprops
                (lambda (x y)
                  (let* ((xp (string-match-p "\\+\\'" (car x)))
                         (yp (string-match-p "\\+\\'" (car y)))
                         (xbase (if xp (substring (car x) 0 -1) (car x)))
                         (ybase (if yp (substring (car y) 0 -1) (car y)))
                         (posx (cl-position xbase order :test 'string=))
                         (posy (cl-position ybase order :test 'string=)))
                    (cond ((and posx posy)
                           (< posx posy))
                          ((and posx (not posy))
                           t)
                          ((and (not posx) posy)
                           nil)
                          (t
                           nil))))))
    (mapc (lambda (x) (org-entry-delete nil (car x))) outprops)
    (mapc (lambda (x) (org-entry-put nil (car x) (cdr x))) outprops)))


(defun org-entry-properties-preserve-case ()
  "Get standard properties of current entry.
Extracted from `org-entry-properties' and modified to retain case,
retain + (if suitable but still concat values), and account for empty
property values."
  (org-with-point-at nil
    (org-back-to-heading-or-point-min t)
    (let ((range (org-get-property-block (point)))
          props)
      (when range
        (let ((end (cdr range)) seen-base)
          (goto-char (car range))
          (while (re-search-forward org-property-re end t)
        (let* ((key (match-string-no-properties 2))
               (extendp (string-match-p "\\+\\'" key))
               (key-base (if extendp (substring key 0 -1) key))
               (value (match-string-no-properties 3)))
          (cond
           ((member-ignore-case key-base org-special-properties))
           (extendp
                (let ((old-ext (assoc-string key props t))
                      (old-base (assoc-string key-base props t)))
                  (cond
                   ((and (not old-ext)
                         (not old-base))
                    (setq props (cons (cons key value) props)))
                   (old-ext
                    (setcdr old-ext
                            (concat
                             (cdr old-ext)
                             (unless (string-empty-p (cdr old-ext)) " ")
                             value)))
                   (old-base
                    (setcdr old-base
                            (concat
                             (cdr old-base)
                             (unless (string-empty-p (cdr old-base)) " ")
                             value))))))
           ((member-ignore-case key seen-base))
           (t (push key seen-base)
              (let ((p (assoc-string (concat key "+") props t)))
            (if (not p)                        
                (push (cons key value) props)
                      (setcar p key)
                      (setcdr p
                              (concat
                               value
                               (unless (string-empty-p value) " ")
                               (cdr p)))))))))))
      props)))
```